# dynamic form storage using codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, dynamic, storage

I have a codeigniter form which allows the users to create dynamic fields . 
I am able to store the data  of the default fields in my database  which I have given but how do I store  the data dynamic fields which user generates into my database

```
html code:
   <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Projects</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Step 4</h3>
        <div class="multi-field-wrapper">
      <div class="multi-fields">
        <div class="multi-field">
             <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
        <input type="text" name="ptitle[]" id="ptitle" placeholder="Project Title" />
        <input type="text" name="tech[]" id="tech" placeholder="Project Technology">
        <textarea name="des" id="des[]" placeholder="Description" rows="10" cols="10"></textarea>
        <button type="button" class="remove-field">Remove</button>
          </div>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="add-field">Add field</button>
        </div>

        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
```

controller code:

```
 <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('register');
    }

    public function __construct(){
   parent::__construct();
   this->load->helper('form');
   $this->load->library('session');
   $this->load->library('form_validation');
   $this->load->model('Register_model');
   $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

    }

    public function register()
    {
      $this->load->library('form_validation');  
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('rollno','Rollno','required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass','Pass','required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpass','Cpass','required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Name','required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('branch','Branch','required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('ypass','Ypass','required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('phoneno','Phoneno','required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('address','Address','required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('year','Year','required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('semester','Semester','required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('percent','percent','required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('ptitle','Ptitle','required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('tech','Tech','required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('des','des','required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('achieve','achieve','required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('skill','skill','required');
    if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
    {
      $this->load->view('register');
     return false;
     }


   else
  { 
  $data1 = array(

    'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
    'rollno' => $this->input->post('rollno'),
    'password' => $this->input->post('pass'),

    );

    $data2 = array(

   'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
   'branch' => $this->input->post('branch'),
   'ypass' => $this->input->post('ypass'),
   'phoneno' => $this->input->post('phoneno'),
   'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
   'rollno' => $this->input->post('rollno'),
     );



    // $count = count($this->input->post('h'));
   $yr = $this->input->post('year');
    $sem = $this->input->post('semester');
    $per = $this->input->post('percent');
    $rol = $this->input->post('rollno');
   /* for($i = 0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
    */
    $data3 = array(
     'year' => $yr,
     'semester' => $sem,
     'percent' => $per,
     'rollno' => $rol,
  /*'year' => $this->input->post('year'),
  'semester' => $this->input->post('semester'),
  'percent' => $this->input->post('percent'),
  'rollno' => $this->input->post('rollno'),*/

   ); 
   // }




$data4 = array(
    'ptitle' => $this->input->post('ptitle'),
    'technology' => $this->input->post('tech'),
    'description' => $this->input->post('des'),
    'rollno' => $this->input->post('rollno'),
    );

  $data5 = array(
    'achievement' => $this->input->post('achieve'),
    'rollno' => $this->input->post('rollno'),
    );
  $data6 = array(
     'skill' => $this->input->post('skill'),
     'rollno' => $this->input->post('rollno'),
    );

  // }

  $result = $this->Register_model->register($data1,$data2,$data3,$data4,$data5,$data6);
  if($result == TRUE)
  {
  echo "your are registered successfully!";
  }
  else
  {
  // echo "unable to register,try again!";
    $this->load->view('register');
  }
 }/*else */
    } /*register*/
  } //welcome
?>
```

model for above controller:

```
 <?php
    class Register_model extends CI_model
    {
    public function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();

    }
    public function register($data1,$data2,$data3,$data4,$data5,$data6)
    {
        $this->load->database();
     $condition = "rollno =" . "'" . $data1['rollno'] . "'";
     $this->db->select('*');
     $this->db->from('signup');
      $this->db->where($condition);
      $this->db->limit(10);
      $query = $this->db->get();

      if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {


        $this->db->insert('signup', $data1);

      $this->db->insert('personaldetails', $data2);

        $this->db->insert('academicdetails', $data3);
        $this->db->insert('projects', $data4);
        $this->db->insert('achievements', $data5);
        $this->db->insert('skillset', $data6);
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
    return true;

    }
    }
     else {
    return false;
    }   

    }

    }
```

?>[image: screenshot of the output]

Comment: Please provide some more information & code snippet so we can understand your question better and help you.

Answer (score 2):

You did not provided your html code and some more information, but let me give you an idea.

First, make the dynamic field as an array as i did below:

```
 <textarea name="des[]" id="des" placeholder="Description" rows="10" cols="10"></textarea>
```

Now it does not matter how many new fields are added, it will have the same name as above.

When you get that field in your CI code, the `des` will be an array with all the values. Now you can apply validation to them using loop or what ever you want to do.

To save that fields data in database, it is good to save it in the form of json as below.

```
$des = $this->input->post('des');
$encoded = json_encode($des);
```

This way, it wont matter if you have a single dynamic field or hundred, it will be saved easily. And when you need that data, just fetch it from DB, json decode it as below and loop through it according to your purpose.

```
$dec = json_decode($value_from_db);
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: i have tried the way u have told but i am facing database errors .  this is my controller code:    http://pastie.org/10642881

Comment: what database error do you face? Please note that i just gave you the idea, you have to adjust your code according to it